# Convergence of a Series such that $\{x_{n}\} \neq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What happens when I have any sequence $\{ x_{n} \}$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_{n} \neq 0$. Can I immediately say that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_{n}$ also diverges or does $\{x_{n}\}$ need to be a convergent sequence with $\lim x_{n} \neq 0$?

Comment: It will diverge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call $S_N=\sum\limits_{n=1}^N x_n$ note that $x_N=S_N-S_{N-1}$

Thus $S_N$ converges $\implies S_N\to \ell\implies x_N\to \ell-\ell=0$

So if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n\neq 0$ then the series diverges (by contraposition).

Comment: What happens if the limit for the sequence does not exist?

Comment: many things can happen. for instance if $x_n\to a\neq 0$ then $S_n\sim na\to\pm\infty$. If $x_n=(-1)^n$ then $S_n=0$ or $1$ which does not have a limit either. If $x_n>c>0$ then $S_n>nc\to\infty$. But in the general case, $x_n$ take positive and negative values that just do not sum up in a convergent way. It is hard to describe all cases, there are too many ways of not converging to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

The Divergence test states that if $\sum x_{n}$ converges, then $x_{n}\to 0$. Hence, if $x_{n}\not\to 0$, you automatically know that the series $\sum x_{n}$ diverges.

Comment: Thanks lads, I understand now.

Comment: Instead of $\sum x_n< \infty$ it might be better to say $\sum x_n$ converges

Comment: I've updated my answer.